# Strange MySQL insert syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Just a quick thing,
I am trying to search for a specific string, everything it finds I need to insert into a database

When I run this code:

```
  <?php
    $search = 'permanently'; 
        $logfile = 'ban_list.txt';
        // Read from file 
        $file = fopen($logfile, "r");
        while( ($line =  fgets($file) )!= false)
        {
        if(stristr($line,$search))   // case insensitive
            echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>";
            ?>
            <?php   
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "pass";
            $dbname = "db";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('$line', '$timestamp')";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }

            $conn->close();
        }
        fclose($file);
    ?>
```

I get this error:

```
118441 # reichskommisar is banned permanently by A_GismoDyret.
Error: INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')' at line 1 1213174 # SwagFurMeinFuhrer is banned permanently by HA_Vincent.
Error: INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')' at line 1 1394124 # Kick_Ass is banned permanently by HA_Vincent.
Error: INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')' at line 1    Error: INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')' at line 1    Error: INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')' at line 1    Error: INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')' at line 1    Error: INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')' at line 1    Error: INSERT INTO ingame-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-banlist (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('', '0')' at line 1 1762050 # VladimirKozlov is banned permanently by SO_Conner. # do not unban
```

Did I make a misstake in my syntax? I tried alot of things but I am clueless what it could be.

Thanks

Comment: You need to you backticks around table name because of `-`.

Comment: This is why you should never use characters like `-` in your table names. Use underscore instead.

Comment: Also you should move the connection creation before the while loop. (and close it after)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column or table names containing special characters like  `-` must be escaped with backticks. Use

```
INSERT INTO `ingame-banlist` (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ...
```

Comment: Otherwise, MySQL is interpreting that as `ingame` MINUS `banlist` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Update your insert query and try like this -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ingame-banlist` (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('$line', '$timestamp')";
```

Comment: That is SQL-Server syntax. The question is tagged MySQL.